# Highlighted/Selected areas are black for Imagemapster in IE

Tags: jquery, imagemapster

http://www2.wou.edu/pls/wou2/jalcanter10.video_tour.p_main

The page works fine in other browsers, but I'm not sure what to even look at. The areas do get lit up and selected, but instead of the 2nd image showing, its painting the areas black

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you are linking ImageMapster directly from its github raw source:

```
<script type="text/javascript" 
 src="https://raw.github.com/jamietre/ImageMapster/master/dist/jquery.imagemapster.js"
</script>
```

It is possible you got this idea from a jsfiddle example I posted before. While this works well enough for testing in Chrome, it's definitely no good for a production web site. The reason it doesn't work in IE is because Github does not transmit the correct mime type when serving files from the source tree. Chrome and Firefox don't care, IE does. But more importantly, the script at this location could change anytime. If an update to the development code is pushed that has bugs, it could stop working.

You just need to copy the script to your own server and link to it there.

Comment: I have redirected it to our server, and the issue is the same - the buildings get highlighted and selected both on mouseover and from external links, but instead of the 2nd image, its a black overlay... could it be anything else? And its IE8, in case that helps

Comment: Oh - in IE6-8, altImage does not work. It's not technically possible. See: http://www.outsharked.com/imagemapster/default.aspx?docs.html#altImage

Comment: Well that solves that then :) Thanks for the info. Is there a way I can get the highlighting/selecting to be a fallback color?

Comment: You can just use the regular `fillColor` setting to change the color - it won't have any effect for the browsers that are using `altImage`. It would probably also be good to use something other than `fillOpacity: 1` so you could still see the building info through the fill. I'd check what browser they are using and set the options conditionally, e.g. `if ($.browser.ie && $.browser.version <9) { ... bind with options for ie } else { ..bindd with options for everything else }` this way you can use different opacity for when altImage is not in effect.

Comment: I'm having the same problem, using unreleased 1.2.6.099 (9/21/2012) that I copied down from GitHub to a local js file (I needed the tooltip capabilities). This problem only displaying on ie 8 (haven't tested ie 6,7). Adjusting opacity (0, 1, 10) has had no effect, nor has changing fill color. Opacity of map areas is 100% fillcolor when moused over. It's also causing a stackoverflow error (again, only in ie8).